# Issue with "AS" statement reflecting the same variable

Tags: php, sql, distance

Having an issue trying to calculate distance during my query.
Calculation "AS distance"
And for some reason my "distance" reflects the exact same across several of the results.. when the latitude and longitude are very different.

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($datacon,"SELECT spreadsheet.*,zipcode, ( 3956 * acos( cos( radians( '$lat_A' ) ) * cos( radians( location_latitude ) ) * cos( radians( location_longitude ) - radians( '$long_A' ) ) + sin( radians( '$lat_A' ) ) * sin( radians( location_latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance

            FROM spreadsheet,craft_zipcodes

            WHERE

            spreadsheet.ZIP=craft_zipcodes.zipcode

            and spreadsheet.package='$package'

            and spreadsheet.HIDE_FROM_SEARCH = '0' and spreadsheet.googlezero = '0'  GROUP BY ADDRESS HAVING distance <= $radius ORDER BY distance asc $pages->limit ");
```

You can see the result here:
http://carterbackup.revo-tech.com/locations/?package=BOTTLE&radius=5&custzipcode=37419&brand=AMBER&count=19&folder=1&ipp=5

If you select "ALL" from the pagination.. you can see that every 20-30 rows will show a different distance? I am not sure why...